# error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: DS_SETFONT

Tags: c++

I am starting to learn about the Windows API. So I opened up Microsoft Visual C++ and created a new project. I chose Win32 project and it started up. I then clicked build and run before typing anything and I came up with this error:

```
error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: DS_SETFONT....
```

The error told me it was in the windows resource file that I cannot edit. I looked on-line and I couldn't find anything on this topic.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: Have you added any custom code to the project yet? It doesn't sound like it, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I haven't added any code yet.

Comment: Hrm. Does the auto-generated code have the line `#include <windows.h>` in it? If so, are you familiar with how to check the "include directories" settings in MSVC?

Comment: I am sort of familiar with it, I used it when learning some OpenGL.

Comment: Check the listed "include directories" in the settings to make sure one of the directories contains the file `windows.h`.

Answer (score 13):

When the solution is generated, it removes `#include <windows.h>`.

Simply adding `#include <windows.h>` will fix it.

In my case, I added it in the *.rc file.

Comment: It probably has something to do with your decision *not* to use precompiled headers. Normally, the RC file includes the pre-compiled header, named `stdafx.h` by default. That in turn includes `<Windows.h>`. If you've disabled pre-compiled headers and deleted `stdafx.h`, then you're not including the Windows headers in your resource file. However, I would advise *against* editing the RC file by hand--it's regenerated on demand by the designer.

Answer (score 0):

For others encountering this problem: my issue seems to have originated in that I was working on an old project where the resource files were not generated in Visual Studio and the normal Wizard setups had not been completed.

I was attempting to add/change controls to the MYAPP.RC files defining the menu etc but was getting an error "RC2104 undefined keyword or keyname: DS_SETFONT."  This is because the Symbol Directives needed the header # include "windows.h"

I figured this out and added # include "windows.h" to the resource.h file.  Trouble is both the MYAPP.RC and resource.h files are auto generated and any manually inserted # include "windows.h" gets dumped each time.

This [Microsoft Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn035-using-multiple-resource-files-and-header-files-with-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160#_mfcnotes_tn035_set_includes) page put me straight and I went to the Resource View -> Resource Includes -> Read-only symbol directives window and inserted: # include "windows.h"

Can now edit Resources no problem.