# C++ Setting dll properties via .rc file: Which attributes are shown by Windows 7?

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, rc

I created a dll and set various attributes in the rc file (by following the tutorial [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference#Version_Information). If I scan the dll with exiftool, I can see all of my attributes. However, Windows 7 displays only certain attributes when I right-click on the dll, select "Properties" and then go to the "Details" tab. I can't figure out which attributes I have to set to change the values Windows 7 shows me.

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647130/error-rc2104-undefined-keyword-or-key-name-ds-setfont) answer I had to include windows.h, which solved my problem. The page I linked mentions this only in a completely unrelated example and the [official Microsoft example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't have the include either, but mentions it hidden in the "Remarks" chapter.